# How to implement modal window in asp.net?

Tags: dialog, window, modal-dialog

I'm creating a project in asp.net and I looking for Modal Window (like ajax modal popup) in order to use in all dialogs from my application, the problem is that this ajax component is only compatible with ie but not in safari, firefox, etc...

Anyone knows any modal window that I can use with asp:panels (to include asp controls like textbox, listbox, etc...)?...

Thank you in advance

Javier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is use [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) which loads the content in a iFrame, so for example I have the option in a simple page, and then open fancybox to load that page.

```
SetupDialogBox: function (openerClientID, width, height, effect, showCloseButton, buttonsOn, offsetHeight, onStartHandler, onCompleteHandler, onClosedHandler, refreshParentOnClose) {
    if (effect == null) effect = 'none';
    if (width == null) width = 620;
    if (height == null) height = 680;
    if (buttonsOn == null) buttonsOn = false;
    if (showCloseButton == null) showCloseButton = true;
    if (refreshParentOnClose == null) refreshParentOnClose = false;

    if (offsetHeight == null) {
        // adjust for hight for offset based on apperence of buttons
        if (buttonsOn) {                
            offsetHeight = 180;
        }
        else {
            offsetHeight = 140;
        }
    }

    var adjustedHeight = height - offsetHeight;
    var onStartLocal = function () {
        // If you want to show a loading panel, heres a good place to do it
    };
    var onCompleteLocal = function () {
        $('#fancybox-frame').hide();
        // If you want to hide load panel heres a good place to do it
        a$('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('.modalContent').css('height', height - offsetHeight + 'px'); $('#fancybox-frame').fadeIn(2000); };
        $('#fancybox-frame').bind('load', function () {  $('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('.modalContent').css('height', adjustedHeight + 'px'); $('#fancybox-frame').fadeIn(2000); });
    };

    var onClosedLocal = function () { if(refreshParentOnClose) { parent.location.reload(true); } };

    $('#' + openerClientID).fancybox({
        'width': width,
        'height': height,
        'autoScale': false,
        'transitionIn': effect,
        'transitionOut': effect,
        'padding': 0,
        'scrolling': 'no',
        'centerOnScroll': false,
        'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
        'showCloseButton': showCloseButton,
        'type': 'iframe',
        'onStart': function () { onStartLocal(); if (onStartHandler != null && typeof (onStartHandler) != 'undefined') onStartHandler(); },
        'onComplete': function () { onCompleteLocal(); if (onCompleteHandler != null && typeof (onCompleteHandler) != 'undefined') onCompleteHandler(); },
        'onClosed': function () { onClosedLocal(); if (onClosedHandler != null && typeof (onClosedHandler) != 'undefined') onClosedHandler(); }
    });
},
```

We then insert a link on each page which is the handler for the fancybox frame

```
<a class="menu" href="http://www.whateverurl.com/myBox.aspx" id="menuLauncher" style="display:none;">&nbsp;</a>
```

Fire a Javascript call to setup the box

```
SetupDialogBox('menuLauncher', 820, 360, 'fade', false, null, null, null, null);
```

Then finally a call which opens the box when clicked (if its elsehwere on the page)

```
$("#menuLauncher").trigger('click');
```

alternativly you could just make the menuLauncher visible and use that as a opening link.

Comment: Thank you John... but I can't to implement this sample in my project. I think I don't know some steps that I think I'm leaving out some important step. Could you send me a simple sample code?

Comment: I can't share the entire codebase I'm afraid since a lot of it is in a framework we use, the only thing missing from above would be the jQuery library and the LightBox library (link to lightbox above)

Comment: No problem John, I think that I have the solution. My project its works right now by using jQuery UI. Thank you for your answers...